# sending SMS to the user using fast2SMS

Tags: python, django, authentication, sms

I want to send an SMS to the user in the Marathi language but in fast2SMS it is been send in the default language that is English. I have gone through the API Documentation of fast2sms but didn't found the answer to my query. please help me how can I send the SMS OTP in Marathi.

[image]

```
querystring = {
    "authorization":
        "sender_id":"KAMALCLS",
        "message":"ur password is " +pw,
        "language":"english",
        "route":"p",
        "numbers":str(ph)
    }
    
    res = requests.request("GET",url,params=querystring)
```

Comment: as mentioned in API doc of fastsms you have to give your message in `unicode` format, for it to be recognized

Comment: and what do you want to be send in marathi , text or number ? and do remove or hide your API key from here

Comment: @Abhishek Sir I want to Message the user for example Your Password is "the OTP" . Unicode format like some code just like English have like un-eng

Comment: If you want `your password is ` in marathi i suggest use the unicode string like `u\u0905` and group them together to form a meaning full sentence and replace it with your message string.  in `"message":"<Your unicode string>"+numerical value of your otp` . it will get the job done.

Comment: @Abhishek Sir how I am doing but it's not working as I did in the message: "u\u0905" + "ur password is" + pw

Comment: you have to convert the string to unicode literal `u\u0905` is a unicode string

Comment: @Abhishek Sir I am not getting you, please explain with an example

Comment: if you can type on python console `print('u\u0905')` you'll get what im trying to say. it will print the Marathi char

Comment: @Abhishek Yes Sir I came to know but how to work on message:"ur password is" + pw how to use u\u0905 here

Comment: you have to go char by char follow `http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0900.pdf`, or you can write a function to convert the string to unicode using above chart

Comment: @Abhishek Sir I copied the same code but still not working,Please help me Sir

Comment: @Abhishek Sir in fast2sms documentation I got this for language  language false Default language is "english". API will detect "unicode" message automatically.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this..

```
import requests
url = "https://www.fast2sms.com/dev/bulkV2"
querystring = {
    "authorization":"<YOUR TOKEN>",
        "sender_id":"KAMALCLS",
        "message":u'\u092e' + u'\u0928' + u'\u094b' + u'\u091c',
        "language":"english",
        "route":"q",
        "numbers":"<YOUR MOBILE NO>"
    }
    
print(querystring)
```

if you run this code it will convert the message to unicode you can see name.

Comment: @Abhisekh Sir, I tried the same way but still, it's not working. Help me Sir Please